# Get all HTML data EXCEPT mailto: and tel: in BS4 Python decompose()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to take out phone numbers and Emails from HTML.

I can get the data.

```
description_source = soup.select('a[href^="mailto:"]'),  
                     soup.select('a[href^="tel:"]')
```

But I do not want it.

I am trying to use

> decompose

```
description_source = soup.decompose('a[href^="mailto:"]')
```

I get this error

> TypeError: decompose() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I have thought about using

> SoupStrainer

But it looks like i would have to include everything but the mailto and tel to get the correct information...

full current code for this bit is this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

item_number = '122124438749' 

ebay_url = "http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=" + item_number
r = requests.get(ebay_url)
html_bytes = r.text
soup = bs4(html_bytes, 'html.parser')

description_source = soup.decompose('a[href^="mailto:"]')
#description_source.

print(description_source)
```

Comment: Post your full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `find_all()`. Find all the links in that page and then check which ones contain phone and email. Then remove them using `extract().`

Use `lxml` parser for faster processing. It's also recommended to use in the official documentation.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

item_number = '122124438749' 

ebay_url = "http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=" + item_number
r = requests.get(ebay_url)
html_bytes = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_bytes, 'lxml')

links = soup.find_all('a')
email = ''
phone = ''

for link in links:
    if(link.get('href').find('tel:') > -1):
        link.extract()

    elif(link.get('href').find('mailto:') > -1):
        link.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

You can use `decompose()` also instead of `extract()`.

Comment: Hey, Thats agreat little script and I had fun PLaying with it.. 

However this returns the data i wish to remove.. 

I wish to REMOVE ALL tel: and mailto: HTML.

The whole html has to be downloaded.. Then saved WITHOUT the <a href="tel:0000000"></a> and te same with the tel:

Comment: alos I have changed my parser to XML!

Comment: Hey dude. fantastic.:)